# Importing a project

Tags: eclipse, svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am new to Subversion. I'm using TortoiseSVN as my client and VisualSVN as the server. I want to implement it with fellow programmers who are working with me. Some are using NetBeans as their IDE while others are using Eclipse. My PC is the server and they are the clients.

How do they import a project made by me and make changes to it? Using TortoiseSVN they were able to browse my project, but how they import it in their IDEs and make changes to it? Will I be able to view the changes instantaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a plugin called "Subclipse" and another called "Subversive". They can find and install those to work with their Subversion working copy directly in Eclipse. Netbeans likely has something similar.

Or, once they have a working copy checked out by TortoiseSVN, they can just import it without any special plugins into their IDE. They would use the IDE for development, and use TortoiseSVN to manage all the Subversion aspects outside of the IDE.

You won't see any changes "instantaneously". For you to see their changes, they will first need to "commit" their changes, and then you will need to "update" to see their changes.

Since you're asking a really basic question about using Subversion, I'd suggest reading or at least skimming through important sections in the SVN book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 2):

> Using TortoiseSVN they were able to browse my project

That means they have the url of your SVN repo.
They can load that repo to any folder of their choice.

```
svn checkout http://url/to/your/repo/trunk/ trunk
```

Or (TortoiseSVN)

[image: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.M2/drools-introduction-docs/html/images/Chapter-Install/svn_checkout1.png]

From there, they need to add [subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) to their eclipse:

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_azmyBJVJ09E/SkSLqaWPqHI/AAAAAAAAEOA/I8QsXPq1Re0/s1600-h/svn3.jpg]

They can import an existing project from their SVN workspace.

[image: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.M2/drools-introduction-docs/html/images/Chapter-Install/eclipse_import4.jpg]

Once imported, you can re-connect that Eclipse project to its SVN repo:
(right click on the project, `Team > Share`)

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_aEfX-L_3RIQ/S78-lbHQePI/AAAAAAAAB8g/uD9HVnh_UZ8/s320/Screenshot-Share+Project+.png]

Enter the relevant SVN repo metadata:

[image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_aEfX-L_3RIQ/S78-k0t4rqI/AAAAAAAAB8Q/OCWi0H2gEsY/s1600/Screenshot-Share+Project+Wizard+-1.png]